# What is the best IDE for java android development

Tags: java, android, macos, syntax, ide

What is the best IDE for java development on mac OSX?
Ive been using Sublime text for all of my web based programming and i´m wondering wich IDE is the best one to use while programming apps for android.

Comment: "Which is the best X" is almost always unanswerable in such a broad way and tool-suggestions as well as primarily opinion-based questions are not really at home here.

Comment: @HighCore: "Visual Studio" will not run very well in OS X.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that's why you have Windows 8 instead.

Comment: Android Studio (don't know about best but if you're beginning dev, it should be the easiest)

Answer (score 11):

I prefer [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). Its a new Android development environment based on IntelliJ IDEA. It is Similar to Eclipse with the ADT Plugin.

Android Studio is the Google's recommended IDE for Android development.

Comment: Yes I agree, Google invests money every year to keep it free and well updated in the IntelliJ family of IDEs.

Answer (score 5):

> Android Studio is the official IDE for Android application
>   development, based on IntelliJ IDEA.

See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

It used to be the Eclipse based Android Development Tools (ADT).

Comment: As of now, (2016) Google is recommending use of Android Studio. Your link has changed

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ is now the official IDE for android development.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/

http://developer.android.com/tools/workflow/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://netbeans.org/ or http://www.eclipse.org/. Both work on a Mac.
I prefer Eclipse over Netbeans.